Marketing Cloud SQL - check JSON array size
Inside the Data Extension there's one column that stores a JSON object. One of its key invalid_data is an array that can stores multiple smaller object inside.
You can see the structure below:
{
"message": "Invalid data at import",
"invalid_data": [
    {
        "logical_attribute_name": "SOME_NAME_1",
        "technical_attribute_name": "SOME_NAME",
        "constraint": "SOME_CONSTRAINT",
        "value": "ACTUAL_VALUE",
        "source_table": "SOURCE_TABLE_NAME"
    },
    {
        "logical_attribute_name": "SOME_NAME_2",
        "technical_attribute_name": "SOME_NAME",
        "constraint": "SOME_CONSTRAINT",
        "value": "ACTUAL_VALUE",
        "source_table": "SOURCE_TABLE_NAME"
    }
]

}
What I need to do: I need to validate if invalid_data > 1 then I'd like to iterate trough it and concatenate logical_attribute_name keys and technical_attribute_name into strings - each for separate column.
Problem is that I have no idea how to check the size of array inside JSON as JSON_ARRAY and OPENJSONdoesn't work I've also tried with COUNT.
You can see my current code below:
SELECT 
JSON_VALUE(removal_reason, '$.message') as reason_message,
JSON_VALUE(removal_reason, '$.invalid_data[0].logical_attribute_name') as logical_attribute_name,
JSON_VALUE(removal_reason, '$.invalid_data[0].technical_attribute_name') as technical_attribute_name,
JSON_VALUE(removal_reason, '$.invalid_data[0].constraint') as [constraint],
JSON_VALUE(removal_reason, '$.invalid_data[0].value') as [value],
JSON_VALUE(removal_reason, '$.invalid_data[0].source_table') as source_table
FROM my_table
WHERE removal_reason LIKE '{%'


think about a staging DE into which you break up the JSON; The structure does look rather flat, so you'd get pretty clean "invalid data" rows, which you could easily count() on.

The actual solution that I found is to count repetitions of given string in the JSON structure.
For example: the key "logical_attribute_name" has 22 characters.
With this code snippet I can count a sum of such strings:
SELECT
LEN(json_table) - LEN(replace(json_table, 'logical_attribute_name', '')) as characters

In my situation it was 44, so I know that there are 2 elements in the actual array, so I can call them statically by knowing the actual characters amount:
SELECT
CASE [characters]
    WHEN 22 THEN JSON_VALUE(reason_json, '$.invalid_data[0].logical_attribute_name')
    WHEN 44 THEN 
        CONCAT(
            JSON_VALUE(reason_json, '$.invalid_data[0].logical_attribute_name'), '|', 
            JSON_VALUE(reason_json, '$.invalid_data[1].logical_attribute_name')
        )


I built my own one and the logic is same as @MrSkover
select top 100 CustomerID, LEN(JSON_QUERY(JSON,'$.items')) - LEN(REPLACE(JSON_QUERY(JSON,'$.items'), ',', '')) AS comma_count
from your_table
where LEN(JSON_QUERY(JSON,'$.items')) - LEN(REPLACE(JSON_QUERY(JSON,'$.items'), ',', '')) <= 4
